# Bash script: Avoid empty string arguments

Tags: bash, shell, escaping, argparse, spaces

A bash script shall pass its arguments on to another script, which is a python script in my case:

```
python test.py "$1" "$2" "$3"
```

The python script uses the argparse library and will return with an error, if empty string arguments are present, i.e. the parent script got called with less than 3 parameters.
The reason I use a python script in the example is, because it probably wouldn't be recognized within a subsidiary shell script, if unused "empty string"-valued arguments are present.

One way to circumvent the error, is to check for the number of arguments `$#` and explicitly handle each viable case:

```
if [ $# -eq 0 ]
then
  python test.py
elif [ $# -eq 1 ]
then
  python test.py "$1"
elif [ $# -eq 2 ]
then
  python test.py "$1" "$2"
else
  python test.py "$1" "$2" "$3"
fi
```

Note that I have to quote the arguments, because they may contain spaces.

What alternatives exist to this (bloated) solution?

The solution should not depend on passing on the argument list as a whole. It might be desirable to change the order of arguments or add other local variables as arguments to the python script.

Comment: You could also do `python test.py $1 $2 $3 $4` if you are...hrm...guaranteed to not have spaces in any of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`"$@"` expands to nothing if there are no arguments, so you can simply use

```
python test.py "$@"
```

If you want to make sure a 4th argument to your script (or more) isn't passed to the Python script, use the `bash` extension

```
python test.py "${@:1:3}"
```